# htaccess Rewrite rule from "example.com/de/foo" to "example.de/foo"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, drupal

RewriteRules can be such a pain for me, I cannot get this one to work.
I have to redirect urls like **example.com/de/anypath** to **example.de/anypath**.

[anypath] can be really any path, as I have to get it work for
**example.com/de/articles/programming/hello-world** (would be redirected to **example.de/articles/programming/hello-world**)
as well as for **example.com/de/events/pic-nic** (would be redirected to **example.de/events/pic-nic**).

This is what I wrote so far :

```
 RewriteRule "^/de/(.*)$" "http://example.de/$1" [R=301,NC,L]
```

- I also tried with RewriteCond with no more luck

  ```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} http://example.com/de
  ```
- I am working with xampp, but tested on my web server with same
  result.
- I know this `.htaccess` file is working (get error if I enter a
  typo)
- I got some result when testing with something like :

  ```
  RewriteRule "^(.*)$" "https://google.com" [R=301,NC,L]
  ```

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: `RewriteRule ^de/(.*)$ http://example.de/$1 [R=301,NC,L]` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule "^/de/(.*)$" "http://example.de/$1" [R=301,NC,L]
> ```

In `.htaccess`, the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash. ie. It should be `"^de/(.*)$"`, not `"^/de/(.*)$"`.

You don't need the double quotes and the `NC` flag is probably redundant, unless you also need to match `dE`, `Ed` or `DE`.

For example (near the *top* of the root `.htaccess` file):

```
RewriteRule ^de/(.*) http://example.de/$1 [R=301,L]
```

(HTTP, not HTTPS?!)

The trailing `$` on the `RewriteRule` *pattern* was also redundant.

Test first with 302 (temp) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} http://example.com/de
> ```

The `Host` HTTP request header (ie. the value of the `HTTP_HOST` server variable) contains the *hostname* only. eg. `example.com` only in your example.

Any server variable that is prefixed with `HTTP_` refers to the HTTP request header of the same name.

> I got some result when testing with something like :
>
> ```
> RewriteRule "^(.*)$" "https://google.com" [R=301,NC,L]
> ```

Careful with testing 301s since they are cached persistently by the browser. You will *need* to clear your browser cache before testing!

Answer (score 0):

I added two conditions (the first is to apply according to local or live site, the second to leave the node paths unchanged) :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} local.example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/de/node/.*$
```

And it is working as expected. Thanks again.